# How to enable/disable 3g data service in Android?

Tags: android, settings

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

I need to make an aap for android which requires enabling the 3g data service at first. Please let me know different ways of changing the settings values eg. adb shell commands or APIs/library which can be used. Links to examples will be more useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to stackoverflow.com

found answer: [How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

```
Method dataConnSwitchmethod;
Class telephonyManagerClass;
Object ITelephonyStub;
Class ITelephonyClass;

TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

if(telephonyManager.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED){
    isEnabled = true;
}else{
    isEnabled = false;  
}   

telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
Method getITelephonyMethod = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
ITelephonyStub = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
ITelephonyClass = Class.forName(ITelephonyStub.getClass().getName());

if (isEnabled) {
    dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass
            .getDeclaredMethod("disableDataConnectivity");
} else {
    dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass
            .getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity");   
}
dataConnSwitchmethod.setAccessible(true);
dataConnSwitchmethod.invoke(ITelephonyStub);
```