# How to disable data connections(3g/gprs) on android

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

I know that this is possible in version 2.2 and below but since 2.3 it is not possible, unless you have a application that has a certificate supplied by google that specifies it as a secure application or if you place your application in the /system/app directory. I have attempted to place the application in the system/app dir and found this to be impossible on the emulator even with su rights. How would I make my application secure for android market (so google will give me the certificates required) or install the application to the system/app dir. The only other possibility is to use the ndk, but i am not so sure if it will work and the time and effort that would have to go in to hack around this will just be a pain. Can some one assist in the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling 3G using methods provided by the SDK is not possible, anyway I think I remember a solution where the APN was set to a invalid one to kind of disable 3G

**EDIT**:
I just figured out that APNDroid uses exactly this renaming-workaround to disable the 3G connection. 
[Here](http://code.google.com/p/apndroid/source/browse/) you can browse the source code of the application

Comment: Can you give me a link to follow, or some thing that I can search on. I have already looked at APN Settings and they did not work Successfully. I do know that if you get a system certificate, which is what is used by Samsung for their system apps then it should work.

Comment: please see my edit - you can browse the APNdroid code to figure out how to do that

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look :)