# How to enable data connection on Android 2.3

Tags: android

Referring to [How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android) , we know the approach to enable/disable data connection in Android 2.2 by java reflection.
However, in Android 2.3 and up, `android.permission.MODIFY_PHONE_STATE` is no longer supported and I found the way above does not work in Android 2.3. Do you have another idea to enable data connection?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ConnectivityManager mgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
Method dataMtd = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
dataMtd.setAccessible(true);
dataMtd.invoke(mgr, true/false);
```

you need **android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE** permission too

Comment: Hi, Thanks. The only issue is that it cannot stably enable data connection in my HTC EVO 4G -- although the widget seems enabled but it is not really data connected. (Disabling data connection is always okay)

Comment: I get following runtime error java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 2):

You also need to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

to the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

In your androidmanifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

;)