# Turning on internet connection programmatically (Android)

Tags: android, connection, 3g

I am developing a software for android which I want to turn on user's internet connection automatically. Like these internet on/off widgets does.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) throws Exception{
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    Class conmanClass = null;
    try {
        conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

this is for 3g activation similar goes for wifi

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WifiManager to call setWifiEnabled

More detail here :

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html

Comment: This method was deprecated in API level 29