# Programmatically enable and disable gprs in android

Tags: android, gprs

As per my requirement . I want to enable and disable GPRS Programmatically.I Googled for a day , did not able to find any suitable solution for it.
Is it possible to Enable and Disable GPRS through our code...if yes the give me some valuable link or ideas to do this.As  **apndroid** Application use the same thing to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Take a look at this so [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

Comment: Yes..but This does not work on 2.3 or any higher version of android OS

Comment: Did you look at second answer (that is not accepted)?

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android/8962211#8962211)

Comment: Which solution worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this could help you:

[How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

Furthermore u can check the current connectionType (GPRS, 2G, LTE etc) with

```
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
telMgr.getNetworkType()
```

The TypeConstants are defined in the TelephonyManager Class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html

GL

Comment: Hi Thomas K. I have already looked in to the API but there is no such method to Enable or disable GPRS/Internet Connection.

Comment: The solution of the link I posted contains a working code that uses reflection. Afaik this is a good workaround for enabling/disabling connections. Did u try it?

Answer (score 0):

The code written in this OpenSource project might be usefule to you to switch GPRS.

[Check Here](http://code.google.com/p/gprswall/source/browse/trunk/src/com/pdaXrom/android/gprswall/GPRSWall.java)

I haven't tried so far..so can't write more.

Comment: this example required installed commands 'su' and 'iptables'.