# Trouble shooting push notifications with urbanairship

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

When trying to manage an app using urbanairship and trouble shooting 'missing' push notifications, I decided to write a Q&A to assist other developers.

The most common complaint from clients is, a user on a  device didn't get a notification.

Occasionally a whole group will miss out on notifications causing me to examine the client app and urbanairship dashboard to figure out what has happened.

The most common errors I have found on the dashboard have been:

> Received error: Received push with missing authorization on platform
>
> GCM Received error: Received push with invalid authorization on
> platform GCM
>
> Application does not have permission to send to this
> device Original Message: Error: mismatched sender ID

And I wanted to share how I have resolved these.

Answer (score 1):

There are several points that can cause  errors:

1. **Mismatched gcmsender ids with project number**

In the airshipconfig.properties `gcmSender = #########`

> [The Mismatch Sender](https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/70861233-GCM-Troubleshooting-Guide) ID error happens when your Sender ID is incorrect. Ensure you're using your project number, not ID.

[image]

2. **Mismatched API keys**

[image]

In the urbanairship dashboard, go to settings -> services

[image]

3. **Mismatched package names**

The package name is optional, if they do not match though this will cause a problem and it can be removed altogether - the package name, not the service!

[image]

4. **Lack of internet access**
   One thing I am wary of is users with lacking IT skills knowing how to use an app, and I don't overlook internet access.

> - If notifications only arrive when connected to WiFi, confirm that
>     Background data is enabled.
> - Background data needs to be enabled on
>     devices. Otherwise pushes can't send from GCM to Android devices until
>     they have active WiFi connection. Pushes are lost after they leave
>     Urban Airship. To enable background data for each version of Android
>     OS, please consult Android documentation. nb*

5. **Enabling notifications on the device**

> - Notifications are not
>     enabled for the application itself. Notifications are enabled or
>     disabled in the Manage Applications screen. Navigate there for each
>     Android OS by selecting Show Notifications.

[image]

[image]

The quotes are taken from Urbanairship [GCM Troubleshooting Guide](https://support.urbanairship.com/entries/70861233-GCM-Troubleshooting-Guide)

nb* There are no reasonable ways of ensuring mobile data is enabled, at best the user can receive a warning when there is no wifi connection and mobile data is disable [Latest update on enabling and disabling mobile data programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically)

As an extra:

For notification problems on a specific device I ask the client to complete a form like so:

> **Mobile Type:**
>        Android, iOS, other.
>    **Make:**
>    Example: Sony,
>   Samsung, Apple.
>    **Model**
>   In iOS Example:
>    Settings -> General ->
>   About -> Model = MF325X/A
>   In Android Example:
>    Settings -> About Phone -> -> Model number = E2353
>    **Exact Android or iOS version**
>   In iOS Example:
>     Settings -> General -> About -> Version = 8.3 (12F70)
>    In android Example:
>     Settings -> About Phone -> Android Version

That way any changes in permissions between OS versions, or the way push notifications are managed, or known bugs in a device can be explored also.