# Turning mobiledata on/off in android API 17

Tags: java, android-4.2-jelly-bean

Using android **adb shell** in **API level 17** i can enable and disable mobile data using **svc data enable/disable** but if i tried to do it **pragmatically** it does work and pass with out any exception here is my code

```
    try{ Log.e(TAG,"Before mobile data thread");
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
    DataOutputStream os= new DataOutputStream(proc.getOutputStream());
    os.writeBytes("svc data disable\n");
    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
    os.flush();
    try{
        proc.waitFor();
        if(proc.exitValue() !=255)
        {
            Log.e(TAG,"Disabling mobile data");
        }else{
            Log.e(TAG,"Error Disabling mobile data");

            }

        }catch(Exception e){}
} catch (Exception ex){Log.e(TAG,"IN mobile data exception exception");}
```

any Suggestion how can i disable/enable mobile data

Answer (score 1):

You can not enable or disable mobile data yourself if phone is not rooted or your app is not in device administrator mode. You can only ask user to enable/disable application data.

You can ask user in dialog like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Please turn on mobile data access")
    .setTitle("Unable to connect")
    .setCancelable(false)
    .setPositiveButton("Settings", (dialog, id) -> startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)))
    .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
    .show()
```

For rooted phone use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically)