# Android notifications service

Tags: android, permissions, notifications

I want to know the process flow of android apps like i have an app in my device by which it blocks the apps in background. Eg - If the app is forbidding the whatsapp then there will not be any notification in the device untill and unless the app is opened by user.

I want to basic mechanism how the app is doing this as it blocks the apps and also disable data for that forbidden app.

Comment: you have to cancel notification as they arrive using Notification listener. or you can force stop whatsapp to disable notifications

Answer (score 0):

You can not block notifications of any other Android Application or disable its background processes. You might be able to achieve that on a rooted device but that's something not appreciated.

Again if you want to disable data programmatically, you require a rooted device. You can read that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically).

If you want to achieve Single-Purpose Device, read [here](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html).

Comment: Hi  Novo,  In  my device there is an app named permissions and it shows for how many apps the Auto start is activated that means if the is forbidden in the Auto start the whatsapp messages will be received only when the app is opened.