# Mobile data stays enabled after connecting to a wifi network using WifiManager

Tags: android, wifi

I am connecting to a wifi network using this code:

```
    String SSID = "Alarm";
    String pass = "Alarm1234";

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + SSID + "\"";
    conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + pass + "\"";

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

    if(!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    }

    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

    wifiManager.disconnect();

    wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks().forEach((WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration) -> wifiManager.disableNetwork(wifiConfiguration.networkId));
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
    wifiManager.reconnect();
```

and it works fine. The problem is however, that while connected to the new wifi-network, mobile data stays enabled as well (the 4g icon is still showing), and this is a problem for my application. When I close the app, the 4g icon dissapears. I need it to turn off while I'm still in the app. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use an if-else which will disable mobile data if wifi is enabled and vice-versa

Comment: @PrajwalW As of android 4.4 you can no longer disable or enable mobile data programatically

Comment: Since it cannot be enabled/disabled programitically, the workaround patch can be if wifi enabled- prompt user to go to settings and disabled it- when clicked on OK, intent starts which opens up the network settings!

Comment: @PrajwalW yes this could be an option but it seems stupid, why can't mobile data just disable when I'm connected to the wifi network, why does it only happen *after* the app is closed? There must be some kind of explanation

Comment: Try to play your code within the activity lifecycle. As that may help since it disables as u close the app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482526/9166855  Check this answer

Comment: @PrajwalW You need root for this, I don't have root and obviously you can't require your users to root their phone (unless it's one of those root-apps)

Comment: Yes, lets hope for some other quick patch amswers here!