# how to Enable/disable Aeroplan mode or Enable/disable Mobile data in android studio

Tags: java, android

Can anyone tell me how to enable or disable Aeroplane mode(Flight mode) or mobile-Data(Cellular -Data) programmatically? 
I already read many answers on stack-overflow,I tried some code but none of them worked most of the methods are deprecated or no longer exist. 
So is there any way to do that?

Comment: Please add the code you tried, it is not possible to know what isn't working or is working for you

Comment: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533881/toggle-airplane-mode-in-android<br> (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically <br> (3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.