# How can I turn on/ off mobile data in android studio using a button?(should support >=Android5.0)

Tags: android-studio, mobile-data

Below is my **mainActivity** class and also I enabled CHANGE_NETWORKSTATE, INTERNET, ACCESS_NETWORKSTATE permissions in **Manifest** file.

For below code, I tested, (**when I am pressing the button nothing happens**)

A big thanks if someone can figure out the bug here:)

NOTE: My wifi should remain ON before and after this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = findViewById(R.id.download);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                NetworkRequest.Builder request = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
                request.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);
                request.addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                connectivityManager.requestNetwork(request.build(), new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Latest update on enabling and disabling mobile data programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically)

Comment: Short answer: not possible ...

Comment: No that doesnot answer my question

Comment: Yes it does, because it clearly states, that it's not possible to do what you want, because you need an extra permission, which is not possible to aquire for standard apps.