# How can i enable/disable mobile data Java Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, mobile-data

I would like to know how to enable or disbale mobile data of the user's phone. I already have read a lot of things about that but nothing is working and all is very old.
I f you can help me i would really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is a duplicate question here you have a link to an "updated" answer [Latest update on enabling and disabling mobile data programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically)