# android mobile data/3G

Tags: android, mobile

how can I disable and enable the mobile data(3G) on Android?

I read that I need to use the connectivity manager. However, I still don't understand how I can enable and disable the mobile data?

I found this, however, it doesn't work for me,

Can anyone explain me what can I do to turn on and off the mobile data?

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
switch (telephonyManager.getDataState()) {
        case TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED:
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, false);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.DATA_DISCONNECTED:
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, true);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for you? Does it crash? If yes, post the logcat crash report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

Against which api level are you developing? Logcat as Siddharth suggest ...
Too less informations top help you appropriate