# Disable Mobile Data

Tags: android, android-internet

i need to disable mobile data connection programmatically

i followed this

```
private void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled) {
    final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
    final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
    iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
    final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
    final Class iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
    final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

    setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
}
```

[StackOverFlow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

but i got a Error "java.lang.NullPointerException:Println need a message"

Log

```
09-05 18:20:29.081: E/AndroidRuntime(736): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
09-05 18:20:29.081: E/AndroidRuntime(736): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-05 18:20:29.081: E/AndroidRuntime(736):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
09-05 18:20:29.081: E/AndroidRuntime(736):  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
09-05 18:20:29.081: E/AndroidRuntime(736):  at com.anand.batterysaver.BatterySaverActivity.checkScreenStatus(BatterySaverActivity.java:69)
09-05 18:20:29.081: E/AndroidRuntime(736):  at com.anand.batterysaver.BatterySaverActivity$1.run(BatterySaverActivity.java:43)
09-05 18:20:29.081: E/AndroidRuntime(736):  at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

checkScreenStatus Function

```
 public void checkScreenStatus(){
        PowerManager powermanager;
        GetProcessList list = new GetProcessList();
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        powermanager = (PowerManager) this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE); 
        if (powermanager.isScreenOn() == false)
        {
            Log.d("PowerStatus","Lock All Settings");
            boolean gprsstatus = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
            Log.d("Locked gprsStatus",String.valueOf(gprsstatus));
            if(gprsstatus == true){
                try{
                    list.setDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), false);
                }catch (Exception e) {Log.d("Exception",e.getMessage()); }
            }
        }else{
            Log.d("PowerStatus","Resume All");
            gprsstatus = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
            Log.d("Locked gprsStatus",String.valueOf(gprsstatus));
            if(gprsstatus == true){
                TelephonyManager gprs = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if(gprs.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED){
                    Log.d("Gprs","on");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :
This works (this is a code of one of my apps on the market)

```
private static void updateAPN(Context paramContext, boolean enable) {
    try {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) paramContext.getSystemService("connectivity");
        Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
        setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(connectivityManager, enable);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Bonus :

```
private static boolean isAPNEnabled(Context paramContext) {
    try {
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = ((ConnectivityManager) paramContext.getSystemService("connectivity")).getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return networkInfo.isConnected();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

By the way, don't forget this :

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
```

Comment: its raises exception Println needs message

Comment: Hum, I looked a bit more to your exception, it seems it's not thrown from your setMobileDataEnabled function, right ?

Comment: Please post the complete stacktrace of the code of this function : turnData

Comment: i renamed Turn data into setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled)

Comment: Ok, sorry, just saw you edited : what is this function : checkScreenStatus

and what's on the 69th line of BatterySaverActivity.java:69

Comment: Log.d("Locked gprsStatus",String.valueOf(gprsstatus)); ?

Comment: Try Log.d("gprsStatus : ",gprsstatus);

Comment: its just give boolean value if its on it gives true if its off it gives false

Comment: i cleared nullpointer exception now i got InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 0):

I used the same method, but I added throws Exception, like this:

```
public static void setMobileDataEnabled(Context context, boolean enabled)throws Exception {
       final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager)  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
       final Class conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
       final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
       iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
       final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
       final Class iConnectivityManagerClass =  Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
       final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
       setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);

       setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, enabled);
    }
```

in this way a method called

```
    try {
    Tools.setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), true); //true for enable, false for disable
    } catch (Exception e) { }
}
```

and it works for me.

Comment: i dont need to enable i need to disable that

Comment: Tools.setMobileDataEnabled(getApplicationContext(), false);
change this line like this, this will disable connection.

Comment: same error java.lang.NullPointerException:Println need a message