# Prohibit the mobile Internet in the background "Android"

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to disable Mobile Data on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

I'm sorry for my English, I use a translator.
In the android menu, you can turn off mobile data in the background. How can I do this using code?

Answer (score 0):

You as a programmer are responsible for the behaviour of your program, so if you don't want that your program uses data when in the background:

- Test for it.
- When in background, don't make call's.

Comment: I want to disable it for all programs

Comment: That is an Operating system responsibility, to my knowledge you can NOT do it from code.