# Xamarin for android: Start / stop 3g on device

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I need to be able to start / stop the 3g on the device. How do I go about doing this?

So far I have tried the following to start the service if it's not already but to no luck:

```
        var mobileManager = (ConnectivityManager)baseActivitySherlock.GetSystemService(Context.ConnectivityService);

        var mobileStatus = mobileManager.GetNetworkInfo(ConnectivityType.Mobile);

        if (mobileStatus.IsAvailable && !mobileStatus.IsConnectedOrConnecting)
        {
            mobileManager.StartUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityType.Mobile, "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");               
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to disable Mobile Data on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android)

Comment: Not entirely - I have tried the method stated there and I don't think ITelephony interface is available in the Xamarin build :/