# Android Eclipse Turn Off 3G/Mobile Data

Tags: android

I want to turn off the 3G or Mobile data and activate WiFi as soon as the 3G/Mobile Data is off.
id manage to turn off and on the WiFi but have not managed to do the same to the mobile data/3G.
does anyone have an idea how to turn off mobile data when i click a button?

Comment: This requires you to use hidden APIs via reflection. These hidden APIs are known to change between versions of Android. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644144/how-to-disable-mobile-data-on-android

Comment: What does this have to do with eclipse?

Comment: this havnt worked for me..

Comment: Please It havnt worked,must be another way...im using 4.2.1 btw